# Merging 2 data frames based on date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames.
First data frame

| Harvest date | Room | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22.10.2021 | ABT1 | 120 |
| 21.11.2021 | ABT2 | 100 |
| 22.10.2021 | ABT1 | 10 |
| 21.11.2021 | ABT2 | 2 |

Second data frame

| Harvest date | Content | Thc lvl |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22.10.2021 | flower | 10 |
| 21.11.2021 | flower | 2 |
| 11.02.2021 | flower | 3 |

What I need as a result:

| Harvest date | Room | Quantity | Content | Thc lvl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22.10.2021 | ABT1 | 120 | flower | 10 |
| 21.11.2021 | ABT2 | 100 | flower | 2 |
| 22.10.2021 | ABT1 | 10 | flower | 10 |
| 21.11.2021 | ABT2 | 2 | flower | 2 |

I tried to merge the 2 data frames using an outer join on Harvest date. But it doesn't give the result I want.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Flower_weight.csv')
print (df1)
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Analyses.csv',encoding= 'unicode_escape')
print (df2)

df = pd.merge(df1,df2,how="outer",on="Harvest date")
```

Can someone help me merge those 2 data frames the way I need please?

Comment: did you try `how='left'` ?

Comment: it is giving me what I need but I have no values for Content or Thc lvl, Could it be because there is no match in Harvest Date?

Comment: According to the example dataframes you gave, it works fine and the Content and Thc lvl columns are not empty. if these two columns are empty, yes you have no matching value.

Comment: I gave a simplified version of my situation. I have different time formats. But changing to a left join was really helpful. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Clegane could you please post an answer to my question? The left join did the trick. Thank you one more time!

Comment: I have one more small related question. If I have in my second table duplicate dates what happens? 1. Does the merge pick the first date and ignores the rest? 2, Does it replicate the data from the second table as well?

Comment: if second df has rows with the same date, yes, it replicate the data. but as a result they will have different  Content  and Thc lvl values

Comment: Before using merge, I also recommend using the drop_duplicates function. This leaves rows with all the same values.